# jQuery `.click` Conditional not responding to `else`

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, onclick, conditional-statements

I have a function which checks whether my `trigger` element has a class `.collapsed`, and the `target` element by adding the '.expanded' class. However, the animation only occurs once, and only when the condition is `true`. For some reason, the `false` branch is ignored. Here is my function:

```
function toggleArrow(){
  var target = $(this).find('img.arrow');
  if($(this).hasClass('collapsed')){
    $(target).addClass('expanded');
  } else {
    $(target).removeClass('expanded');
  }
}

$('.foo a').click(toggleArrow);
```

#### Edit:

Created a Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/OP1yHNihDe#

#### Solution:

Used @Binvention answer and removed the `else` branch, replacing `addClass`/`removeClass` with `toggleClass` like so:

```
function toggleArrow(e){
  var target = $(this).find('img.arrow');
  if(!$(this).is('expanded')) {
    $(target).toggleClass('expanded');
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, is there code that *removes* the class `collapsed`? If not, the condition can never be `false`.

Comment: can you put in a fiddle ?

Comment: this is a native Bootstrap plugin called Collapse.js: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse. Everything works as expected and `.collapse` gets added / removed when the `target` is expanded of collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would instead have a single class that either is either collapsed or expanded (collapsed would be easier since the default display on objects is block which shows on the web page) and then just use the `.toggleClass()` function. It's simpler and the result should be the same. So your code would look like this:

```
function toggleArrow(){
  var target = $(this).find('img.arrow');
  $(target).toggleClass('collapsed');
}
```

Comment: this was my original solution. The issue is that Boostrap's Collapse JS may take longer to load and if a user clicks on the arrow twice, the animation logic would get reversed (i.e. the arrow would be `.expanded` when the div is collapsed)

Comment: I'm not familiar with bootstrap but it might be possible you could set a variable to false every time the toggle class is called then once the bootstrap animation is done processing set the variable to true then only run the toggle class if the variable is true

Comment: so adding `.toggleClass` in true branch worked. Why `removeClass` in `else` wouldn't work is beyond me... Isn't `.toggleClass` just a shorthand for `addClass` / `removeClass`? Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Toggle class is kind of and if else for adding and removing classes if it's already there it removes it if it's not there it adds it